# How can I know the directories used by an application

Tags: applications, storage, files

I've been testing some dictionaries the last few days and right now I've my SDCard with plenty of directories with many MB of data that belongs to those dictionaries.
How can I find out for a particular application (may be other than a dictionary) the list of directories it's using?

Comment: I removed the `application-space` tag and denied your edit to its wiki because all other uses have been for the space available for installing applications, not the space belonging to an application.

Comment: @Matthew: ok, I thought its meaning was what I'm asking here. No problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, unless the particular app provides a way.  The Android OS doesn't manage or keep track of where apps decide to write on the SD card.

Comment: You can always try emailing the developers and asking nicely.